# Purge strategy for parent-child persistent objects

Tags: intersystems-iris

We are seeing performance issues in purging objects/tables that have parent-child relationships defined. Due to the number of child objects, we're seeing a very long duration to purge a single parent and all child tables. Is there a better way to do this and get a more performant purge task?

I was thinking to purge the child tables individually first and then delete the parent is one way. Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the child objects via IRIS SQL.
In this approach, you can see the query plan and maybe add the necessary indices.

Answer (score 0):

"purge a single parent and all child tables".
As you want to delete the parent too,
it should be sufficient to delete just the parent object.
By definition, all children should be deleted implicitly.
BUT:
most of the processing time may be consumed by the maintenance of all related indices.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...may take the maintenance of all related indices"*? Do you mean *"...may* ***be taken by*** *the maintenance of all related indices"* (my emphasis)? Or something else? An ideal response would be by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69002882/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: changed answer as suggested